# 2 computers, same browser, same LAN using sse : session_write_close() has different behavior

Tags: php, session, server-sent-events

I have designed a web site which uses sse. Call is made to a php file, which is roughly like :

```
session_name('kflow'); session_start();
$file = $_SESSION['somefile'];
session_write_close(); // to avoid the hang
$oldcontent = file_get_contents($file);
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header('Connection: keep-alive');

while(TRUE) {
   $content = file_get_contents($file);
   if ($content != $oldcontent) {
      $oldcontent = $content;
      push_to_sse($somedata);
   }
   usleep($somelittlenap);
}
```

All this used to work perfectly, in France, in multiple environments, including on my french macbookpro. I then arrive in Frisco, and buy an iMac. Still works perfectly on the macbookpro, it hangs on the iMac, exactly like if there was no session_write_close. Tried on another iMac : same thing. Tried on another LAN : same thing. All have the same browser (firefox, or chrome); all browsers have same version, and no extension. Networks setting is the same (no proxy, no firewall). All are on the same LAN, and still : only the french macbook pro works, all other computer hangs...

How is it possible to debug this mystery ?

Many thanks !
Best

Comment: Check the Apache log. I bet it is file permissions.

Comment: Thx ! Haven't seen anything in the log. Again, it works with some computers, so I don't see how it is a back-office issue ?